# fpdf multiple calls to fpdf class

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a list of customers who need to get a dynamically generated pdf.

```
 class PDF extends FPDF
 {
 // Page header
 function Header()
 {
            global $backToTOC;

     // Logo
            $this->Image('logo.jpg',70,10);
            $this->Write(5,'Back to TOC',$backToTOC);
     // Arial bold 15
     $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
     // Move to the right
     // Line break
     $this->Ln(20);
 }

 // Page footer
 function Footer()
 {
     // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
     $this->SetY(-15);
     // Arial italic 8
     $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
     // Page number
     $this->Cell(5,'Contact support: 1-800-support');
     $this->Cell(5,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');

 }
 }

foreach ($customer as $k => $v)
 {
 $pdf = new PDF();
 $pdf->AliasNbPages();
//....pdf stuff.....
 $pdf->Output($v.'.pdf','F');
 }
```

the result of this is a divide by zero error.

```
 PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /var/www/lib/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 796
```

and the footer page numbers show 0.  any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The `Cell` method expects the second parameter to be the cell height, not the cell content (see [Cell method](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm)). When calling:

```
$this->Cell(5,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
```

you are using `'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}'` as the height and `0` as the content. It should be:

```
$this->Cell(5, $cellHeight, 'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your font right after creating the PDF object, it worked on my machine.

Also if it doesn't work, please paste a stacktrace.